# What characters should be restricted from a Unix file name?

Tags: validation, unix, file

Consider a **Save As** dialog with a free text entry where the user enters a file name as free text, then clicks a **Save** button.  The software then validates the file name, and saves the file if the name is valid.

On a Unix file system, what rules should be applied in the validation such that:

- The name will not be difficult to manipulate later in terms of escaping special characters, etc.
- The rules are not so restrictive that saving a file becomes non-user-friendly.

So basically, what is the *minimum* set of characters that should be restricted from a Unix file name?

Answer (score 66):

The *minimum* are slash ('/') and NULL ('\0')

Comment: The minimum is /, ; and | to avoid the user running arbitrary commands (assuming it's not escaped :))

Comment: This. No characters besides '/' should be disallowed.

Comment: And ASCII NUL '\0' since that marks the end of the file name :D

Comment: This is the rigourous answer.  The application should be coded to assume that the user was this unconstrained (so when opening files, it should accept any name).  It isn't such a good answer for saving (new) files; it is reasonable to put some limits on the file names.

Comment: @mouviciel : given some filesystems like ꜰᴀᴛ support the ɴᴜʟʟ character. What would happen if the ɴᴜʟʟ character is present in the middle of a filename.

Comment: @user2284570: I don't know. My bet is that it is not possible in the context of a "Save as..." dialog box.

Comment: @mouviciel : in the case the filename was recorded from an another ᴏꜱ of course.

Comment: I'd add ' and "" since they can at least lead to troublesome unmatched quote situations at times.  () too, shells don't like those.  : is a separator in paths.

Answer (score 44):

Firstly, what you're describing is [black listing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklist).  Your better option is to [white list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist) your characters, as it is easier (from a user perspective) to have characters inserted rather than taken away.

In terms of what would be good in a unix environment:

- a-z
- A-Z
- 0-9
- underscore (`_`)
- dash (`-`)
- period (`.`)

Should cover your basics. Spaces can be okay, but make things difficult.  Windows users love them, unix/linux don't. So depending on your target audience choose accordingly.

Comment: Newlines are a nuisance.  Commas are pretty harmless.  Colon would do no damage in Unix, but are problematic if the name is copied to Windows - or if the 'file' is a directory that might need to be added to PATH.

Comment: There is some room to argue that any characters classified as 'isalpha()' in the current locale are OK - that allows people to use accented characters in the names.  It complicates the story, though.

Comment: i for one will regard anything that probits accented characters as user-unfriendly

Comment: What happens with file names in different languages?

Comment: colons are problematic in Linux if it's a directory name that is in your $PATH variable - colons are used as separators in the $PATH

Answer (score 28):

Although the accepted answer might have truth I think there's a benefit to having some restrictions that could be potentially annoying for scripting or other stuff:

- forward slash (/)
- backslash (\)
- NULL (\0)
- tick (`)
- starts with a dash (-)
- star (*)
- pipes (|)
- semicolon (;)
- quotations (" or ')
- colon (:)

( - maybe space though I'm reluctant to add that.)

As you can see you might just be better off whitelisting as @Gavin suggests...

Comment: This is a pretty good list. I would also suggest excluding "!" though, which might be used for history expansion when typed interactively. Oh, and leading periods (hidden) and "<" or ">" (redirection).

Comment: And keep in mind that you still might run across spaces, tabs, and newlines in filenames in Unix.  Your code shouldn't blow up just for seeing that.

Comment: @ThinkBonobo would the list also apply to latest macOS. i ask because it is based on UNIX, i think?

Comment: @JulesManson the list I gave was to best support cross OS support so it should also apply to macOS. Note Macs will probably support some of the items in the list but I just avoid them to avoid compatibility issues elsewhere.

Answer (score 23):

Often forgotten: the colon (:) is not a good idea, since it's commonly used in stuff like $PATH, i.e. the list of directories where executables are found "automatically". This can cause confusion with DOS/Windows directory names, where of course the colon is used in drive names.

Comment: also ldd on linux can get confused looking for rpaths if there are colons present

Comment: If you have a colon in the file name, and you use that partition on Windows and delete the file, it will result in file system corruption. It can be resolved with Windows' "repair disk" tool though.

Answer (score 11):

Do not forget that you can add a dot (`.`) at the beginning to hide files and folders... Otherwise, I'd follow a *NIX name convention (from Wikipedia):

Most UNIX file systems

- Case handling: case-sensitive case-preservation
- Allowed character set: any.
- Reserved characters: `/`, `null`.
- Max length: 255.
- Notes: A leading . indicates that ls
  and file managers will not by default
  show the file

[Link to wikipedia article about file names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename)

Answer (score 10):

## Encode FTW

As [Bombe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43582/bombe) points out in their answer, restricting user input is at least frustrating if not downright annoying. Though, as developers we should assume that every interaction with our code is malicious and treat them as such.

To solve both problems in a practical application, rather than white-or-black-listing certain characters, we should simply not use the user input as the file name.

Instead, use a safe name (hex chars `[a-f0-9]` only for ultimate safety) of our own devising, either **encoded** from the user input (e.g. [PHP's bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)), or a randomly generated ID (e.g. [PHP's uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)) which is then mapped by some method (take your pick) to the user input.

Encoding/decoding can be done on the fly with no reliance on mapping, so is practically ideal. The user never needs to know what the file is *really* called; as long as they can get/set the file, and it *appears* to be called what they wanted, everyone's a winner.

By this methodology, the user can call their file whatever they like, hackers will be the only *people* frustrated, and your file system will love you :-)

Comment: Excellent advice!  It's the same principle as storing names as `name` rather than trying to enforce `first` and `last` separately (which makes me *so mad*).  Or when I run into _any_ restrictions on passwords other than _minimum_ length.  ("No spaces allowed?!? For what earthly reason!?")  Obviously this is more appropriate in some situations than others.  Sometimes you _have_ to let the user specify the actual file name for perfectly valid reasons.

Answer (score -3):

Let the user enter whatever name he wants. Artificially restricting the range of characters will only annoy the users and serve no real purpose.

Comment: Or, better: '$(rm -fr $HOME)' (minus the single quotes) as the file name?  That will wreak havoc sooner rather than later.  Backticks and $(...) are particularly pernicious as they 'work' when the file name is quoted, unlike most of the other special characters.  Embedded quotes are tricky, too.

Comment: Those are all non-issues when saving the filename. fopen() doesn’t care about your filenames. When using a graphical shell (e.g. konqueror) it doesn’t care about your filenames. When you use auto-completion in the shell it doesn’t care about your filenames. So what are your points? :)

Comment: @Bombe, what one user might want in many cases will alienate other users, regardless of the havoc it plays with your UI development process. Bad idea.

Comment: That’s my point: choosing strange names will not wreak havoc with anything—unless your “anything” is badly written. None of the standard tools of UNIX is badly written. Again: what’s your point?

Comment: What a short sighted answer from someone that really should know better. Your answer didn't even properly answer the original question. They say `The name will not be difficult to manipulate later in terms of escaping special characters, etc.`. People have noted here that there are quite a few characters that *can* be in valid file names, but realistically cause a bunch of problems.