# Linux Rename file with only time/date stamp

Tags: terminal, file-rename

I have a single file which I want to rename mv to year_month_day_h:m:s - whats the best way to do that?

I've tried the following but it doesn't dynamically add the correct stamp (original file actually has a backslash in the name):

`mv getnw/myfilename.txt "%Y%m%d%H%M%S".txt
mv getnw/myfilename.txt "%Y-%m%d%H%M%S".txt
mv getnw/myfilename.txt %Y-%m%d%H%M%S.txt
mv getnw/myfilename.txt "'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S'.txt"`

Comment: Use `mv`. What have you tried?

Comment: Please edit that into your question, and please also add a bit more details about exactly what the source file name looks like (i.e. a real example filename) and what you're trying to automate.

Comment: Note that while most filesystems don't have a problem with `:` in file names, there will be a problem getting this file to a Windows-compatible filesystem, as those treat `:` as a special character.

Comment: Piskvor: that's correct. it works on linux/mac but it's generally bad idea to use special chars in file names.

Comment: @dsomnus: There's nothing "special" about punctuation. I for one like the fact that I can use a complete sentence for a file name, without having to replace all punctuation with `_`. Oh, wait, `.` is allowed in NTFS filenames. But is `,`? Maybe. And `!` is okay, but `?` means trouble. Or was it the other way around? Fun fun fun with arbitrary rules from the 1980s :-(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
mv myfile.txt `date +%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M:%S`.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mv myfile.txt myfile`date -Is`.txt
```

is a shorter version

but `:`  won't work with some of the unix commands like rsync or scp because it parses part of the name as a host address. use `tr` to change `:`

```
mv myfile.txt myfile`date -Is|tr : -`.txt
```

or

```
mv myfile.txt myfile$(date -Is|tr : -).txt
```

Comment: Right, the colon is also not usable in all filesystems or computer systems. See [Allowed characters in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/) and [What characters should be restricted from a Unix file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457994/).