# Rename file command in Unix with timestamp

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Hello I'm using Putty and trying to rename a file name with current timestamp.

I've used following command to rename the files and according to date

```
mv abc.log $(date +%F)prod.txt
```

Above command renames but not able to rename with time, it giving output as

```
2014-05-12prodabc.log
```

And following command

```
abc.log $(date +%y)$(date +%m)$(date +%d)abcprod.log
```

giving output as

```
140512abc.log
```

Actually my requirement is as following:

- Rename `abc.log` to `abc-<current timestamp>.log`

  - e.g `abc.log` become `abc-12-05-2014-17:31.log`
- Then create new file `abc.log`

Please Help, Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux Rename file with only time/date stamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639088/linux-rename-file-with-only-time-date-stamp)

Answer (score 39):

You can use

```
mv test.dat test_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).dat
```

If you want to know how you can control your output have a look at the date Manpages..

```
man date
```

Answer (score 14):

Use this:

```
mv abc.log $(date +%F-%H:%M).log && touch abc.log
```

Here,

`+%F-%H:%M` will give you a format like `2014-05-19-14:47`.
If the renaming has done successfully, `touch` will create a new empty file.

Answer (score 3):

This this:

```
 str=abc; mv ${str}.log ${str}-$(date +%F'-'%T).log
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel to create a cron job: be careful that you need back slash for %. 
this works : cp log.txt log.`date +"\%d\%m\%Y"`.txt

Comment: cp log.txt log_\`date +"\%d\%m\%Y"\`.txt

Answer (score 0):

in one-liner version

```
FILE=abc.log ;  BASE=${FILE%%.*} ; EXT=${FILE##*.} ; cp $BASE.$EXT $BASE-$(date +%F'-'%T).$EXT ; > $BASE.$EXT
```