# Renaming file with date using mv command

Tags: linux

How to change the filename from file.txt to renaming it to be file_may_20_2020.txt
using mv command?

I have used

```
mv file file_(`date`).txt
```

I still don't know how to put a command inside another command

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733669/rename-file-command-in-unix-with-timestamp) answer your question?  Use the search, Luke. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either

```
mv file file_"`date +"%B_%d_%y"`".txt
```

or

```
mv file file_"$(date +"%B_%d_%y")".txt
```

Answer (score 0):

mv file file_"$(date +"%B_%d_%y")".txt

What you put inside the $ is like a template string and its value is placed in the string