# What characters are illegal on the filename on iOS or OS X?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, filenames, hfs

What characters are illegal on the filename on iOS or OS X?

For example, char "/" is illegal. I need to remove all of them and only them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://superuser.com/questions/326103/mac-os-x-lion-what-are-invalid-characters-for-a-file-name](http://superuser.com/questions/326103/mac-os-x-lion-what-are-invalid-characters-for-a-file-name)

Comment: I needs to be noted that OS X ignores case while iOS doesn't.

Comment: @HotLicks OS X can be setup with a case-sensitive filesystem like iOS. It all depends on the filesystem you choose when formatting a partition.

Comment: Illegal? No one is going to arrest you. Invalid, perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Illegal characters on the HFS file system:

- `:` - illegal char.
- `/` - it's poor to use it.
- `\0` - not sure, but don't use it too.

Comment: Only `:` is illegal.  `/` is the path separator and `\0` terminates the string, so is impossible to use.

Comment: trojanfoe: HFS+ uses Pascal strings, not C strings, so `\0` is perfectly legal.  TN1150 even describes the rules for how they are sorted: http://dubeiko.com/development/FileSystems/HFSPLUS/tn1150.html#HFSPlusNames

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as any *nix filesystem. See this post: [What characters should be restricted from a Unix file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457994/what-characters-should-be-restricted-from-a-unix-file-name)

Comment: iOS and OS X uses HFS or HFS+ file system with its own restrictions.

Comment: Why I can't use ":" on the Finder app?

Comment: It looks like it's the same: http://superuser.com/questions/204287/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-os-x-filenames

Comment: Check out the first comment on the accepted answer

Comment: @Altaveron: The OS X Finder translates "/" from to UI to ":" in the file system. So from the user's view, "/" is an allowed character but ":" it not. The reason is probably historical. The old Macintosh file manager functions (I don't remember what they were called exactly) used ":" as the path separator.

Comment: I think you are not right. I can't use ":" on Finder and can use "/".