# Name of a Flutter project contains semicolons

Tags: android, flutter

My app name contains spaces and semicolons, which is the reason that one of the libraries (ImageGallerySaver) doesn't work as it should. Is there any workaround if I don't want to change my app name?

```
<application
    ...
    android:label="App name with spaces and : semicolons"
    ...
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin `ImageGallerySaver`, to work, creates `folder` in your device `Local Storage` which name is the same as your app name. Since a folder name cannot contain the caracter `:`, this is why you are encoutering issues

Comment: That's true, thank you very much! I've also noticed that another library (Wallpaper manager) doesn't work if my app name contains spaces. Should I use underscores or some corresponding characters to get my name in google store written as " My app: Hello World", but in manifest "My_App%44Hello_World" or are there some other standard practices for that? Sorry for so many questions, forget all about it if it's too much.

Comment: Have a look a this https://stackoverflow.com/a/458001/14231239

Comment: Also if your question is answered, you can mark the answer as the correct one